# Get all Radio boxes Names & Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get all the values of each radio box that is selected, each radio box has a unique name, except two. Two have the same name but different values.

Code I have is:

jQuery: (For a test, this just alerts and doesn't save to the database yet)

```
$(':radio:checked').each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong>View My Tickets</strong>
    </td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">
        <input name="NAME" value="Allow" div="Permissions" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td width="25%" align="center">
        <input name="NAME" value="Deny" div="Permissions" type="radio">
    </td>
</tr>
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KvdNq/3/

Comment: When is the JavaScript executed? Is it maybe inside a click event?

Comment: Hi Jacques i'm currently running it in JS Fiddle, before I actually put it into my code.

Comment: This works when I test it though. Do you want to check the values whenever someone selects something?

Comment: Yes, I am writing different fiddles now trying to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To alert the value of a radio box when someone checks it, do the following:

```
$(":radio").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvdNq/11/)

Comment: Thank you!! I cant believei t was this simple, I hate jquery sometimes

Comment: @NoMansLand No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: @NoMansLand Put the alert inside of the `success` function. If the alert doesn't pop up then, it means that the error lies in your PHP file.

Comment: @NoMansLand Also, `var dataString = ...;` needs to be moved outside of the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(':radio:checked').each(function(key, value){
  alert($(value).val());
});
```

Note that with given HTML code,it will not alert anything since no radio box is checked

Having

```
<input name="NAME" value="Allow" div="Permissions" type="radio" checked>
```

It will result in alert with value `Allow`

See http://jsfiddle.net/KvdNq/8/

Comment: I was wanting it to change on every change, so if I click on Allow it will work, i click on deny it will work for each box...

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what do you exactly want to do. I can see that what you have posted works for me.

The issue I can see is that both JS will run as soon as the script is downloaded from the server. By that time you would not have made any selections.

What you need is probably an event emitter (ex: a button) and a listener function that gets executed when the event occurs.

ex, I added a button to your HTML:

```
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

and I modified your js as:

```
document.getElementById('clickMe').onclick = function myAlerts() {
  $(':radio:checked').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
  });
}
```

Let me know if this helps. Thanks